# Setting expectations on MoQ

Tags: parameters, installation, moq, verify, expectations

I'm using MoQ to test some controllers I have. I'm not able to set the expectations. This is the code I have:

```
        var rep = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        rep.Setup(r => r.Save());
```

The problem is that my `Save()` method expects a `User` object which I cannot set in the expectation because an instance of it will be created by the controller. Is it possible to set expectation without passing a specific parameter, and just check if the method was called no matter what parameter was passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you explain what you mean by "the Save() method expects a User object"? Does it expect it as a parameter? If so, you can define that in the setup:

`rep.Setup(r => r.Save(It.IsAny<SomeObjectType>())`

And it'll take in any object as long as its type is `SomeObjectType`.

If you meant something else, then please show a code sample of what the expected behavior is.

Comment: That's correct. I just found it myself. I was trying with It.IsAny<Object>() while my method expected a User parameter. I used It.IsAny<User>() and it worked.

Thanks a lot!